# Does the default power bi auto date/time for new files support hourly view?

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, data-manipulation, powerbi-desktop

I have auto date/time for new files enabled.

My model has a table with DateTime, Business Unit, Sales.

The date time values are hourly. For example: 26-09-2023 10:00:00

When I load this data into Power BI, create a table visual and add the DateTime it auto shows me a hierarchy of year, quarter, month, day. Where as I just want to see the date and time value as shown in example above.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the field well, click the drop down and select the name of your column instead of "Date Hierarchy". Here, my date column is called "My Date"

[image]